# Easy way to send a message to an XMPP/Jabber conference room? (Shell or Python, Debian wheezy)

Tags: python, xmpp, send, command-line-interface, conference

What is an easy way to send a message to a XMPP/Jabber conference room? Either at the command line (Shell), or by using Python? Ideally, all commands and/or libraries should be available in Debian wheezy (or jessie), without using pip.

Answer (score 2):

I had some problems in getting python-pyxmpp to work, maybe I was just to impatient. Anyway I found another solution, that worked for me, but using sleekxmpp for their website. The solution is not better (nor worse, I hope) than goncalopps, only I got it faster to work on Debian wheezy.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-sleekxmpp
```

and here's the code:

```
import optparse
import sys
import time

import sleekxmpp


class MUCBot(sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP):
    def __init__(self, jid, password, room, nick, message):
        sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP.__init__(self, jid, password)
        self.room = room
        self.nick = nick
        self.add_event_handler("session_start", self.start)
        self.message = message

    def start(self, event):
        self.getRoster()
        self.sendPresence()
        self.plugin['xep_0045'].joinMUC(self.room, self.nick, wait=True)
        self.send_message(mto=self.room, mbody=self.message, mtype='groupchat')
        time.sleep(10)
        self.disconnect()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    op = optparse.OptionParser(usage='%prog [options] your message text')
    op.add_option("-j", "--jid", help="JID to use")
    op.add_option("-n", "--nick", help="MUC nickname")
    op.add_option("-p", "--password", help="password to use")
    op.add_option("-r", "--room", help="MUC room to join")
    opts, args = op.parse_args()

    if None in [opts.jid, opts.nick, opts.password, opts.room] \
       or len(args) < 1:
        op.print_help()
        sys.exit(1)

    xmpp = MUCBot(opts.jid, opts.password, opts.room, opts.nick,
                  " ".join(args))
    xmpp.register_plugin('xep_0030')  # Service Discovery
    xmpp.register_plugin('xep_0045')  # Multi-User Chat
    xmpp.register_plugin('xep_0199')  # XMPP Ping

    if xmpp.connect():
        xmpp.process(threaded=False)
    else:
        print "connect() failed"
```

Not sure, whether the plugin for `xep_0199` is really needed.

Comment: Poking around, I noticed that 'jid' must include username + server (e.g. myuser@myjabber.domain.com). Does the room also require some sort of domain on it? I'm having issues getting a chat message to go through. Issue might lie elsewhere but for clarify wondering if you could add example values for your params.

Answer (score 1):

First

```
apt-get install python-pyxmpp
```

Then, something like this

```
from pyxmpp.all import JID,Iq,Presence,Message,StreamError
from pyxmpp.jabber.muc import MucRoomState, MucRoomManager, MucRoomHandler
from pyxmpp.jabber.client import JabberClient
from pyxmpp.interface import implements
from pyxmpp.interfaces import *
from pyxmpp.streamtls import TLSSettings

def execute(user, password, tls_option, message_handler, idle_function, delay=1):
    global client, roomManager
    tls_settings= TLSSettings(require = True, verify_peer = (tls_option!='tls_no_verify'))
    client= Client(JID(user), password, tls_settings)
    client.connect()

    EchoHandler.message= message_handler
    roomManager = MucRoomManager(client.stream);
    roomManager.set_handlers()


def joinMUC( handler, room_jid, nick, password= None):
    global roomManager
    handler.password= password
    roomState = roomManager.join( room=JID(room_jid), nick=nick, handler=handler, history_maxchars=0, password= password )
    return roomState

from pyxmpp.jabber.muc import MucRoomHandler
roomManager= None
execute(username, password, 'tls_no_verify', process_message_callback, periodic_callback)
state= joinMUC( room_handler, "conferencename@mydomain.tld", user, passwd)
state.send_message("something spammy!")
```

I cannibalized this from some old code I had laying around, and I have no means to test it right now, but it should be a good starting point. Feel free to improve it

Comment: I `apt-get install`ed `python-pyxmpp python-xmpp`, but both `import xmpp; xmpp.execute(...)` and `import pyxmpp; pyxmpp.execute(...)` raise `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'execute'`.

Comment: My bad, I apparently had a module called `xmpp`- bad idea. I've cannibalized more code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *Gajims remote_control* for that task. You get the option for OMEMO-encrpytion on top.

First activate *remote_control* in Gajim in preferences -> advanced -> advanced config editor. Then restart Gajim.

Now you can send a message via terminal:

```
gajim-remote send_groupchat_message to@xmppserver.com 'Hello'
```

In python you can use *subprocess*, for example:

```
from subprocess import call
call(gajim-remote send_groupchat_message to@xmppserver.com 'Hello', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I first used *python-xmpp*, but the package is not available any longer on Ubuntu 20.04, likely because it only seems to work with Python 2.x.

The *python-sleekxmpp* alternative in @user923543's answer by now is [deprecated in favor of Slixmpp, a fork which takes full advantage of Python 3 and asyncio](https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP).

In [Slixmpp](https://lab.louiz.org/poezio/slixmpp)'s documentation, there's [an example application](https://slixmpp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/sendlogout.html) that allows sending a single XMPP message.
This works well on Ubuntu 20.04 / Python 3.8, but had errors on Ubuntu 18.04 / Python 3.6 (which also isn't officially supported).

I'm reproducing it here to avoid stale links; note that even though the header says *This file is part of Slixmpp.*, it was not part of the package that I had installed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Slixmpp: The Slick XMPP Library
# Copyright (C) 2010  Nathanael C. Fritz
# This file is part of Slixmpp.
# See the file LICENSE for copying permission.

import logging
from getpass import getpass
from argparse import ArgumentParser

import slixmpp


class SendMsgBot(slixmpp.ClientXMPP):

    """
    A basic Slixmpp bot that will log in, send a message,
    and then log out.
    """

    def __init__(self, jid, password, recipient, message):
        slixmpp.ClientXMPP.__init__(self, jid, password)

        # The message we wish to send, and the JID that
        # will receive it.
        self.recipient = recipient
        self.msg = message

        # The session_start event will be triggered when
        # the bot establishes its connection with the server
        # and the XML streams are ready for use. We want to
        # listen for this event so that we we can initialize
        # our roster.
        self.add_event_handler("session_start", self.start)

    async def start(self, event):
        """
        Process the session_start event.

        Typical actions for the session_start event are
        requesting the roster and broadcasting an initial
        presence stanza.

        Arguments:
            event -- An empty dictionary. The session_start
                     event does not provide any additional
                     data.
        """
        self.send_presence()
        await self.get_roster()

        self.send_message(mto=self.recipient,
                          mbody=self.msg,
                          mtype='chat')

        self.disconnect()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Setup the command line arguments.
    parser = ArgumentParser(description=SendMsgBot.__doc__)

    # Output verbosity options.
    parser.add_argument("-q", "--quiet", help="set logging to ERROR",
                        action="store_const", dest="loglevel",
                        const=logging.ERROR, default=logging.INFO)
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--debug", help="set logging to DEBUG",
                        action="store_const", dest="loglevel",
                        const=logging.DEBUG, default=logging.INFO)

    # JID and password options.
    parser.add_argument("-j", "--jid", dest="jid",
                        help="JID to use")
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--password", dest="password",
                        help="password to use")
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--to", dest="to",
                        help="JID to send the message to")
    parser.add_argument("-m", "--message", dest="message",
                        help="message to send")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Setup logging.
    logging.basicConfig(level=args.loglevel,
                        format='%(levelname)-8s %(message)s')

    if args.jid is None:
        args.jid = input("Username: ")
    if args.password is None:
        args.password = getpass("Password: ")
    if args.to is None:
        args.to = input("Send To: ")
    if args.message is None:
        args.message = input("Message: ")

    # Setup the EchoBot and register plugins. Note that while plugins may
    # have interdependencies, the order in which you register them does
    # not matter.
    xmpp = SendMsgBot(args.jid, args.password, args.to, args.message)
    xmpp.register_plugin('xep_0030') # Service Discovery
    xmpp.register_plugin('xep_0199') # XMPP Ping

    # Connect to the XMPP server and start processing XMPP stanzas.
    xmpp.connect()
    xmpp.process(forever=False)
```